# Submatrix question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading Analytical Geometry of Three Dimensions by DMY Sommerville (first published in 1934). It's hard going - I think because a) the author is overly concise, and b) pre-computer maths seems to have focused on certain topics which, in the computer age, are less needed. Here's one problem I'm having trouble with. Three equations: $$x1 + l1\cdot t1 = x2 + l2\cdot t2$$
$$y1 + m1\cdot t1 = y2 + m2\cdot t2$$
$$z1 + n1\cdot t1 = z2 + n2\cdot t2$$. Then he says, "Between these three equations we can eliminate $t1, t2$ and we get...":

$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
x_{1} & -x_{2} & l_{1} & l_{2}\\
y_{1} & -y_{2} & m_{1} & m_{2}\\
z_{1} & -z_{2} & n_{1} & n_{2}
\end{array}\right)=0$

But how? I've looked at a dozen books on matrices and linear algebra, and there's surprisingly little on submatrices of non-square matrices. Can anyone help? The elimination process gives: $(x_1 -x_2)\cdot(m_1n_2 -m_2n_1) + (y_1 -y_2)\cdot(l_2n_1 -l_1n_2) + (z_1 -z_2)\cdot(l_1 m_2 -l_2m_1) = 0$.

Comment: I think it's supposed to read, $$\det\pmatrix{x_1-x_2&l_1&l_2\cr y_1-y_2&m_1&m_2\cr z_1-z_2&n_1&n_2\cr}=0$$

Comment: Of course it is! What an idiot I am! Thank you very much.